# rearrange randomly placed divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a couple of draggable divs that are placed randomly on the page when loaded

i want these divs to be rearranged to a pre-specified location on the click of a link, how would i go about doing this?

here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbKsq/7/

```
$("#web01,#web02").each(function () {
var randHigh = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - 200));
var randWide = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width() - 200));
$(this).offset({
    top: randHigh,
    left: randWide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem if you already generated that much of a code?

```
$('#organize').click(function() { // just add id="organize" somewhere
    $('#web01').offset({
        top: 20, // this is that pre-specified position
        left: 20
    });
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: half the time i don't know what i'm doing, i compiled this by looking and combining other people's codes.

thanks a lot though, but now if i want to organize web02 to for instance top:40 left:40 by clicking the same link, how would this look?

Comment: you probably wanna change `offset` to `animate` to make it cooler :D

Comment: Just put the same `offset` fire for `#web02` in the `click` callback (that is the first `function`). Also: try to read some js theory and it'll all become far easier